# Vue 3 - How to rename reserved keyword exposed via toRefs()?

Tags: javascript, typescript, vue.js, vuejs3, vue-composition-api

Using Vue 3's Composition API, is it possible to rename reserved keywords when using `toRefs()`?

*[vue/no-parsing-error] Parsing error: The keyword 'package' is reserved.*

```
setup(){
    const data = reactive<Foo>({
        ...
        package: {
            ...
        }
    })
    return { ...toRefs(data) }
}
```

```
<template>
    {{ package.bar }}
</template>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Linter error specifically refers to `{{ package.bar }}` and not to object key directly, which is allowed. That `toRefs` is in use doesn't matter because it's already plain object that has the property in discussion and isn't reactive itself:

```
{ ...toRefs(data) }
```

A different name can be assigned to object property in any way that is available in JavaScript, e.g. with a shallow copy:

```
const { package: packageItem, ...dataRefs } = toRefs(data);
return { packageItem, ...dataRefs };
```

Comment: It didn't even strike me that toRefs() could be destructured. Thank you.